# Limiting keras/ Anaconda's resources on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, keras, anaconda, ram

I'm running a Keras-based neural net on Windows. A lot of my parameters are *large*, and it causes issues with RAM and swapping. It'll cause my computer to slow down so much it's unusable, and won't finish running.

Thing is, I don't care how long the program takes to run, I just want to run it once.

I know resources works in Linux, but I don't know the equivalent in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the batch sizes. Use cpu mode if gpu memory is too low.